# What is wrong with my javascript save and load buttom in html?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to make an idle game (one of those that you have to click a lot of times)

Something is wrong. I want to create a save buttom that saves the actual number of lives and a load buttom that loads the number of lives you had saved.

(Vida is the same as Life but in portuguese)

```js
function save() {
  localStorage.setItem("lifecount", lifecount);
}

function load() {
  lifecount = localStorage.getItem("lifecount");
  lifecount = parseInt(lifecount);
  document.getItemById('text').value = lifecount;
  document.title = lifecount + " Vidas";
}

function add() {
  lifecount = lifecount + 1
  document.getElementById('text').value = lifecount;
  document.title = lifecount + " Vidas";
}
```

```html
<a href=# onclick="add()">ADD<img src="img/planet.png"></a>
<br><br> Já existem:
<input type="text" id="text" disabled style=t ext-align:center> Vidas
<br><br>

<buttom><a href="#" onCLick="save()">Salvar</a></buttom>

<buttom><a href="#" onClick="load()">Carregar ultimo Save</a></buttom>
```

Comment: what is the error you get? you can see the errors of your javascript in the console (in your browser).

Comment: "Something got wrong" doesn't tell us anything about the problem.  *What* is wrong?  What isn't working?  When you debug, where/how specifically does it fail?

Comment: Sorry about the lack of information, first time using the forum

Comment: click.html#:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: save is not defined
    at HTMLAnchorElement.onclick (VM310 click.html:1)
onclick @ VM310 click.html:1

Comment: Uncaught ReferenceError: load is not defined
    at HTMLAnchorElement.onclick (VM310 click.html:1)
onclick @ VM310 click.html:1

Comment: I dont know what "save is not defined" means

Comment: it means the function save doesnt exists

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works.

in your `load()` function you should replace `document.getItemById('text').value=lifecount;` with `document.getElementById('text').value=lifecount;`

you just made a typo on the `getElementById`

```html
<html>
<head>
<title>Click Creator</title>
<script>
var lifecount=0;
</script>
</head>
<body>

<a href=# onclick="add()"><img src="img/planet.png"></a>
<br><br>
Já existem:
<input type="text" id="text" disabled style="text-align:center">
<script>
function add() {
    lifecount=lifecount + 1
    document.getElementById('text').value =lifecount;
    document.title=lifecount + " Vidas";
}

</script>
Vidas
<br><br>

<buttom><a href="#" onCLick="save()">Salvar</a></buttom>

<buttom><a href="#" onClick="load()">Carregar ultimo Save</a></buttom>


<script>
function save() {
    localStorage.setItem("lifecount", lifecount);
}
function load() {
    lifecount = localStorage.getItem("lifecount");
    lifecount = parseInt(lifecount);
    document.getElementById('text').value=lifecount;
    document.title=lifecount + " Vidas";
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: @Caio let me know if this helps. If yes please accept the answer.

Comment: Try to add explanation in your answer and point OP towards the problem. This answer can get negative votes otherwise.

Answer (score -2):

```html
<script>
  var lifecount = 0;

</script>
<html>

  <head>
    <title>Click Creator</title>
  </head>

  <body>

    <a href=# onclick="add()"><img src="img/planet.png"></a>
    <br>
    <br> Já existem:
    <input type="text" id="text" disabled style=t ext-align:center>
    <script>
      function add() {
        lifecount = lifecount += 1;
        document.getElementById('text').value = lifecount;
        document.title = lifecount + " Vidas";
      }

    </script>
    Vidas
    <br>
    <br>

    <buttom><a href="#" onCLick="save()">Salvar</a></buttom>

    <buttom><a href="#" onClick="load()">Carregar ultimo Save</a></buttom>
  </body>

  <script>
    function save() {
      localStorage.setItem("lifecount", lifecount);
    }

    function load() {
      lifecount = localStorage.getItem("lifecount");
      lifecount = parseInt(lifecount);
      document.getItemById('text').value = lifecount;
      document.title = lifecount + " Vidas";
    }

  </script>

</html>
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, it would be better to explain how it solves the problem without introducing others and why to use it. Code-only answers are not useful in the long run.

Comment: Please put the first script tag at least in the `head` section not above the `html` tag. It's not even a valid xml/html file.